# How to save a pandas DataFrame table as a tempory png file or bytes without saving locally

Tags: python, pandas

I try to save my DataFrame as png file  using `dfi` - it's realy great if i save it locally but i need to save it on a memory like a temp file and then push to amazon s3 (try temp file but not work).

How i can achieve this?

```
import dataframe_image as dfi
import boto3 


session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id='<key>',
           aws_secret_access_key='<secret>',
        )

dfi.export(final, '<in memory>')

s3.meta.client.upload_file('<from memory>',
                                   'pdpublickbucket',
                                   'df_custom.png'
                                   )
```

Comment: I can't find a `dfi` on PyPI - where is it from please? Please click [edit] and show your `import` statements.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added import

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work but I have never used that package so there may be a better way. I did this because the documentation said it accepts a *"file-like"* object with a `write` method as parameter - hence `BytesIO`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi
from io import BytesIO

# Generate dummy Pandas-thing
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,4))

# Make "in-memory" buffer and export to it from dpi
buf = BytesIO()
dfi.export(df, buf)

# Pick up result
PNG = buf.getvalue()
```

[image]

---

If you look at the first few bytes you can see it has a PNG signature:

```
PNG[:20]
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00...'
```

Or you can write it to disk:

```
with open('result.png','wb') as fd:
    fd.write(PNG)
```

Comment: but how to upload to amazon?  without saving to locally?

Comment: I don't know - you didn't put your `import` statement in your question for whatever `s3` is.

Comment: i added boto3 in import (s3 - amazon cloud storage)

Comment: That still doesn't tell me what `s3.meta.client.upload_file()` is or where it is documented...

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Comment: Try `s3.upload_fileobj(buf, ...)` You might need `buf.seek(0)` before that in order to *rewind* to the start of the buffer.